# How do you remove extra space between x-axis and plot for a geom_density_ridges_gradient() plot in R ggplot that has a discrete y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a plot using ggplot2 in R that has a discrete y-axis. I am using the ggridges package and the geom_density_ridges_gradient() plot type. These plots create a large space between the bottom of the figure and the labels of the x-axis. Is there a way to remove or shrink this added space?

Here is the code I'm using to make the plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)
library(scales)
 sample_q <- ggplot(data, aes(x=value/1000,y=factor(category),group=category)) + 
   geom_density_ridges_gradient(scale=.5) +
   theme_ridges(center_axis_labels = TRUE,grid=TRUE) +
   xlab("Values") +
   ylab("Height") +
   theme(text=element_text(size=10)) + 
   scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(-15,15), breaks=c(-15,-10,-5,0,5,10,15))
```

I've tried creating the plot with different values of 'scale'. Here are three plots with scale set equal to 2, 1, and .5.

[image: Ridgeplot with scale set to 2]

[image: Ridgeplot with scale set to 1]

[image: Ridgeplot with scale set to .5]

You can see that the space between the bottom of the density plot and the x-axis labels is large and does not change with scales. I've tried without the theme_ridges line as well and the plot still has the same vertical space between the density plot and the x-axis labels. I'd like the x-axis labels to be just below the 'Group A' plot.

Comment: You could try `scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))`.

Comment: Amazing! That worked perfectly. I would happily accept that answer if you post it as an answer.